# javascript: add class to <a> which is clicked and remove all elements with specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

Okay so I have a navigation sidebar and I want it so that when a link is clicked, the .clicked class gets added to the link clicked and the .clicked class gets removed from all other tags, if other tags of a .clicked class. Here is my javascript

```
$('#sidebar ul a').click(function(){
    $('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('.clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

here is my css

```
.clicked {
    background: url(../images/liHover.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -5px 0px;
    color: white;
}
```

and here is my html

```
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">

        <div id="sidebarHeader">

            <h1>top</h1>

        </div>

        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>First</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Second</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Third</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Fourth</li></a>

        </ul>

        </div>
</body>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I click a link / < li > it does add the class however it does not remove the .clicked class from the other elements. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your html is invalid for starters, try putting the li first in the list

```
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        // repeat for other items
```

your jquery is also invalid, your missing the hashtag `'#sidebar'` to reference an id element

finally your jquery function `removeClass` doesn't need a period before the class `removeClass('clicked');`

Comment: Oh wow, okay thanks. But yea, I fixed that much and now, when I click it, it does add the class however, it does not remove all the other .clicked classes which other elements have.

Comment: @user2817200 you need to remove the period before the class on your addClass method

Comment: @JayHarris so it is supposed to be $(this)addClass('clicked'); ?

Comment: @user2817200 i meant removeClass method. you still have the period before the class. `$('#sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('.clicked');`

Comment: @PSL perfect, you got it, I needed to remove the period before my removeClass method, I was trying to removeClass('.clicked') instead of removeClass('clicked');

Comment: @JayHarris wait, on a side not, why does the < a > need to be inside the < li >? It worked fine with the < a > outside of it. I want to make it so that the entire < li > is clickable. I did
$('#sidebar ul a li').click(function(){

Comment: @user2817200 [MDN on ul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#Usage_context). if you want the entire li clickable wrap the < a > around all the li content. it worked but its also invalid html

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

Is your code wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
});
```

If not, your code may be executing before the DOM is ready, in which case it will not bind properly.

Next,

```
$('sidebar ul a')
```

should be

```
$('#sidebar ul a')
```

and

```
$('sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('.clicked');
```

should be

```
$('sidebar ul .clicked').removeClass('clicked');
```

On the CSS side of things, the background won't display on the link unless you set display: block and give it a width. Finally, the image URL inside the parentheses should be in quotes, and as the previous poster stated, the background position should be part of "background" since it's a shortcut.

Comment: Right, I wrapped it in a $(document).ready(function() and then removed the period and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

may be because the a  tag in inline
if you try out  to put it  like a block

```
#sidebarHeader{
  display:block;

}
```

and you should remove the clicked from a element
like this

```
  $('sidebar ul a').removeClass('.clicked');
```